# CSS hyphenation language

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit, hyphenation

Is it possible to define the language used for `-webkit-hyphens:auto`? Does it default to the system language?

```
<p style="-webkit-hyphens:auto" lang="en">
Hyphenated in English
</p>
<p style="-webkit-hyphens:auto" lang="es">
Hyphenated en Español
</p>
```

According to the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/hyphens) the `hyphens` property will use the language specified in the `lang` HTML attribute. However, I can't find any mention of the `-webkit-hyphens` property in the [Safari documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html).

Additionally, does the meta `language` attribute have any effect? Or can this be applied applied to the `html` element?

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNVYr/) I'm using for testing (in Safari and Firefox).

Comment: This article was extremely enlightening:  http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/wiki/en_CSS3Hyphenation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to define the language used for `-webkit-hyphens:auto`?

Yes.

> However, I can't find any mention of the `-webkit-hyphens` property in
>   the Safari documentation.

According to the webkit changelog, it does allow the language to be specified.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43467

You may need to use `-webkit-hyphenate-locale` to get it to work.

> Or can this be applied applied to the html element?

According to this post and its examples, you can set the `lang` attribute right in the element.

http://drublic.de/blog/css3-auto-hyphenation-for-text-elements/

Comment: Safari does recognize the lang element. iOS Safari (at least on the simulator) does not. In that case I used -webkit-locale not -webkit-hyphenate-locale.

Comment: is possible **hyphens** over any string and not limited to X language ?